# Install a stove jack onto a canvas tent without one

Tags: tents, winter-camping, canvas

I'd like to buy a kodiac canvas tent but they don't come with stove jacks.

Not being handy at all, is there any company or store type where I could take the tent to and they could put the stove jack in for me. I know cabela's sells tents with stove jacks but they are way way out of my price range.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to anyone who knows what a kodiac canvas tent is, but in any case it would be good if you could state your location.

Comment: I live in Wisconsin near wisconsin rapids. thank you :-)

Comment: I think specifically with Kodiak tents, they neither offer fire-retardant tents nor do they support adding stoves to their tents. You might want to look into a more traditional canvas tent that comes from the manufacturer with a stove jack, such as [elk mountain](http://www.elkmountaintents.com/) or [kirkham's](http://www.kirkhams.com/wall-tents/).

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using a a stove inside a tent that is not designed for one, is that it will lack the fire retardation treatment on the canvas, and therefore be more liable to catch on fire.

> A: These tents are not fire retardant and should you choose to install a stove Jack somebody could be seriously injured. I guess we care about people. That's what's wrong with us :-) there are plenty of tents out there with stove kits. I'm sure you'll find a perfect fit for your needs.
>   Was this answer helpful?
>
> ...
>
> A: Unfortunately, due to Fire Hazards, we would not recommend it. However there are small electric heaters that would probably be a safer choice.
>
> ...
>
> A: For liability purposes we do not recommend adding a stove jack. I'm sorry for the bad news.
>
> ...
>
> A: The manufacturer does not recommend using any combustible heat source for liability reasons. A wood burning stove requires a air vent and any modifications to the tent void the warranty.

[Competitive Edge Customer Service](https://www.competitiveedgeproducts.com/Kodiak-Canvas-Tent-6051-Six-Person-10-x-10-Ft-Tent_p_12.html?utm_source=GoogleCPC&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=product&dfw_tracker=11389-12)

Comment: I have a question: in a canvas tent not originally designed for a stove, can you just send it back to the manufacturer for retrofitting? I realize that could be manufacturer-specific, but my question is about the possibility. Once the canvas is made, is the fire retardation simply a layer over it, or is it an integral part of the canvas making process?

Comment: @JonathanLandrum I would suggest asking a new question